# Having trouble with Javascript focus()

Tags: javascript

There are 3 programs, Pers1, Pers2, Pers3.  Pers1 and Pers2 have forms to fill in, and Pers3 produces a report.  Pers2 includes Pers1 and Pers3 includes Pers2. Thus if you get as far as a report, both Pers1 and Pers2 are still displayed, and you can adjust your forms if you don't like the report you got.  All of this is written in ColdFusion.

There is Javascript to direct the focus in all 3 programs, and it is working fine.

In Pers3 it is possible to click on the heading of the report and have the Pers1 and Pers2 forms hidden.  This permits the user to print the report without the preceding forms.  To get Pers1 and Pers2 displayed again, you click the heading in Pers3 again.

All is working well except that when I click the heading to get back Pers1 and Pers2, I lose the focus in Pers3.  I've tried lots of things, but so far no success.  The Javascript to switch Pers1 and 2 on and off, including my attempt to refocus (there are 3 divs which have to be shut off/on here):

```
function hider() {

var buttonrep2 = document.getElementById('shutoff'); 
var buttonrep1 = document.getElementById('hiderep1');
var buttontop = document.getElementById('hidereptop');

      if(buttonrep2.style.display != 'none' ) {
         buttonrep2.style.display = 'none';} //shut off

      else {
             buttonrep2.style.display = ''; }//turn on

      if(buttonrep1.style.display != 'none' ) {
         buttonrep1.style.display = 'none';}

      else {

             buttonrep1.style.display = '';}


      if(buttontop.style.display != 'none' ) {
         buttontop.style.display = 'none';}

      else {
             buttontop.style.display = ''};                

 thefocus('reporthead')
}//end of function hider
```

And to refocus, which is working fine everywhere else:

```
  function thefocus(id) {   
  document.getElementById(id).focus();
  }
```

Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong, or how to get this working?

Comment: Can you post your markup?

Comment: The relevant area of the code would help. Just going off the name of it: is `reporthead` a type of non-editable element, such as a header tag? Focus only tends to work well on things that count as input fields.

Comment: I didn't know that -- I'll build an input field.

Comment: I built an empty, invisible input field, and that was fine except there was a cursor blinking in it.  I managed to get rid of the cursor by using type = "button" but then it put in a black dotted line around the middle of the button.  Any further suggestions?

Comment: I think I have gotten rid of the black dotted outline, but the solution below is a bit better, as the button itself was visible even when I set the background color to white.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can focus on non-input elements if you give your HTML a `tabindex` attribute like so:

```
<h1 tabindex="0" id="reportHead">Report Header</h1>
```

And then you can use

```
document.getElementById('reportHead').focus();
```

Comment: Well it did and didn't work.  That is, it certainly refocused for me.  But it also put a black dotted line around the element I was focusing on. Do you know a way to get rid of that?

Comment: Hey, I just found an outline:none, and that got rid of it.  All is now well; the help is much appreciated.

Comment: P.S. If you don't want the user to be able to `tab` to the element, but still want to tab to it programmatically, you can set the value of `tabindex` to -1.

Comment: You know, I don't know what tabindex does, and when I looked it up i got verbiage about tabbing things -- but I don't know what that is.  If you can explain, it would be helpful.

Comment: Tabbing is the act of hitting the `tab` key to move from input field to input field in a form. Its a critical part of UX development for forms as it allows the user to "touch type" or, in other words, the user can fill out a form without needing to lift their hands from the keyboard. In your case, since this is just for scrolling programmatically, you should set at -1 to prevent users from "tabbing" to your header tag.

Comment: Well, I was wondering how to arrange that kind of tabbing, but was not up to that yet.  So now I know. -1 seems fine for my hidden focus, altho it is working well with zero.  On to the next problem.